# vlookup for comma separated cell value with refrence from another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have sheet1

```
**group**                 **Name**
red,white,blue
white, blue,red
blue,red
red,white,blue,pink
```

[image: sheet]

```
sheet2 
Color              Name
red               joe
white             jim
blue              bill
```

[image: sheet]

with multiple records want to multi look up the names for group name in sheet1 
b1 can't use the Office 365 for textjoint. Any other way?

Comment: What is it that you want your final output to look like?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it using VBA.

1. Open VBA editor using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
2. Insert > Module
3. Paste this code:

```
Sub lookup_VBA()

  Dim c As Range
  Dim arr() As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim match As Long
  Dim sResult As String

  On Error GoTo errH
  For Each c In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A10")
    arr = Split(c, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
      match = WorksheetFunction.match(Trim(arr(i)), Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1).EntireColumn, 0)
      If match = 0 Then
        sResult = sResult & "N/A, "
      Else
        sResult = sResult & Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(match, 2).Value & ", "
      End If
      match = 0
    Next
    sResult = Left(sResult, Len(sResult) - 2)
    c.Offset(, 1).Value = sResult
    sResult = vbNullString
  Next
errH:
  If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    Resume Next
  ElseIf Err.Number > 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, , "Error"
  End If

End Sub
```

4. In the code, change `.Range("A2:A10")` with the actual address of data in your "group" column.
5. If needed, change `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` with your actual sheet names.
6. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd>

Results:
[image: vba lookup delimiter comma results]

Comment: Thanks for helping me out its working fine